# Pandas Multiprocessing Can't Get Attribute 'function' on '__main__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-multiprocessing, circular-dependency

I am attempting to use `Multiprocessing` to speed up `pandas` `apply()`.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
num_partitions = 5
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    a,b,c,d,e = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, [a,b,c,d,e]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def square(x):
    return x**2

def test_func(data):
    print("Process working on: ",data)
    data["square"] = data["col"].apply(square)
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = parallelize_dataframe(df, test_func)
    print(test)
```

It is resulting in this error: `Can't Get Attribute 'test_func' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`. I understand this is potentially the result of a circular import somehow, but I'm not sure what to alter in my code. Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Interesting, I can't reproduce this error on my machine, it runs just fine. How are you building and running this code? IDE?

Comment: a jupyter notebook - think that's affecting it?

Comment: Are all these functions in one cell? Or split across multiple cells? If they are split then sometimes when you run code in one it doesn't update with the state of the others. It runs fine for me in one cell in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: they are all in one...but i did just figure out a solution. putting `test_func` and the function it relies on into a separate file then importing that file works like a charm

Comment: I already encountered a similar situation with jupyter notebook and multiprocessing : you have indeed to put your functions in a separate file and import them to be able to use the multiprocess. Not sure about the real reason though...